# Using subscribe function getting cannot read undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I am trying to get information from another component that sends HTTP request with youtube API and I get this problem:

```
Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (profile.page.ts:20)
```

this the component code, from here I trying to get the information from the service:

```
  constructor(private db:FirebaseService,private afauth:AuthService) { 
  this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).subscribe(res =>{
     this.profileInfo= res;
     this.afauth.getYoutubeData(res.channel).subscribe(data =>{
       console.log(data);
  })
})}
```

this the code of the function of the service that send the http request:

```
 getYoutubeData(ch):any{
  let m="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
  part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=" + ch + "&key=" + api ;
  this.http.get(m).subscribe(data =>
  { 
   this.youtubeObj=data.items["0"].statistics;
   return this.youtubeObj;
 })
```

}

Comment: You cannot return data from within subscribe like that, it won’t actually return data. You instead can use RxJS operators such as map() inside of pipe() to pass formatted observable stream data to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your `getYoutubeData` method in the service by removing subscription and returning `this.http.get`. To get `data.items["0"].statistics` from subscription to `getYoutubeData`, use `pipe` & `map` operators:

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getYoutubeData(ch): any {
  let m="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
  part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=" + ch + "&key=" + api;
  return this.http.get(m).pipe(
    map(data => data.items["0"].statistics),
    catchError(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already subscribe in `getYoutubeData` method. You can only subscribe once. In your method please use pipe and tab method like :

```
getYoutubeData(ch):any{
  let m="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
  part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=" + ch + "&key=" + api ;
  return this.http.get(m).pipe(tap(data =>
  { 
   this.youtubeObj=data.items["0"].statistics;
   return this.youtubeObj;
 }))
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `tap` method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you can't basically return data from `subscribe`. So the solution here would be just returning an `Observable` and getting data in the constructor of the component.

**.service.ts**

```
 getYoutubeData(ch):any{
  let m="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
  part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=" + ch + "&key=" + api ;
  return this.http.get(m);
}
```

***.component.ts**

```
constructor(private db:FirebaseService,private afauth:AuthService) { 
  this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).subscribe(res =>{
     this.profileInfo= res;
     this.afauth.getYoutubeData(res.channel).subscribe(data =>{
       console.log(data.items["0"].statistics);
  })
})}
```